# Java eclipse : How to add browse button for Table editable cell?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

In the jface table tutorial [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html)

I can see that in column editing support section

```
JFace provides the following default implementations for cell editors:

TextCellEditor

ColorCellEditor

CheckboxCellEditor

DialogCellEditor

ComboBoxViewerCellEditor
```

but what should be done to implement something like cell displays the path of certain directory and there's a small button in this cell like this image

[image]

Comment: Have you seen that in something in Eclipse?

Comment: No, I didn't see sth like that in eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DialogCellEditor` should do this. It normally just displays a label but switches to a label plus a button when the cell is selected.

You override the `openDialogBox` method to open the dialog you want.

You can also override `createContents` if you would rather have something other than a label (such as a `Text` control).